# textblock in user control TextWrapping not wrapping

Tags: wpf

I created user control with the textblock.  But it will not wrap.  This user control servers as a listboxitem.

```
 <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">


        <Image Height="50" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Name="image1"  Source="{Binding Path=VideoImageUrl}" Margin="12,12,13,84" MouseLeftButtonDown="image1_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="image1_MouseLeave" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >


            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="titleTextBox" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="StackPanelDetails">

                    <TextBlock  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="desciptionTextBox" 
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Desciption, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" />

                <Line />
                <ItemsControl x:Name="CustomItemsSource" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LinksList}" >

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Hyperlink  NavigateUri="{Binding Path=TopicUrl}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" >
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TopicName}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

Comment: Which TextBlock do you mean? I see at least two with TextWrapping="Wrap".

Comment: The second one - descriptionTextBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ListBox's default template does not automatically limit the width of its items, but instead uses a ScrollViewer, which shows a horizontal scrollbar when an item is wider than the ListBox.

You can remove the ScrollViewer by replacing the ListBox's [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx):

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Another important thing to note is that a StackPanel in the top-level Grid won't properly resize the contained elements. In the following simplified example the text in the TextBlock **is not wrapped** because the containing StackPanel simply does not resize it as you expect:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image ... />
        <Text TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=... />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This way it works as you expect:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image ... />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well thanks, that did a bit of a fix - the listboxitem itself is wrapping.  Unfortunetly the textblox text is still not wrapping.

Comment: You should perhaps omit the horizontal StackPanel and define (two?) columns for the top-level Grid. If only your XAML would be more readable... Please consider better formatting.

Comment: The horizontal stack panel is there, so that when image on the left is enlarge, then all the content on the rights slides over - that's intended.  About formatting - I can do a bit more consistent indentation but don't see any other problems with it.

Comment: But the horizontal StackPanel is also the cause of your problem. See my edited answer. The Image can still be enlarged. And yes, proper indentation would significantly improve readability, at least for me.

Comment: I tried the following code on the problem textblock: Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=RightStackPanel}".  Unfortunetly ActualWidth returns values that I do not beleive and so textblock wraps even when supposedly it wouldn't.

Comment: Not necessary, Grid will do the job, if you define columns.

Comment: Well, wrapping problem is fixed.  But with small image I get a hole(  MAy be column definitions have to be fixed?     <ColumnDefinition Width="111*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="480*" />.  Yes, they do: I put Auto to the first one.

Comment: Set Width="Auto" on the first column and no width at all on the second column, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Here it only worked setting Width="*" instead of Width="Auto", but thanks!